# Почему компилятор не видит переменную [c]?

Tags: java

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int k, c, j, a, b, d;
    j = 10;
    b = 2000;
    k = 3000;
    d = 4000;
    a = 1;
    if (j < 100) {
      if (j < 90)
        a = b;
      if (k > j)
        c = k - j;
    } else
      c = d;
    System.out.println(a);
    System.out.println(c);
    System.out.println(k);
}
```

претензия при выводе на печать только к переменной [c]:

**The local variable c may not have been initialized**

Пример надуманный, речь идет только о видимости переменных, так вот, не пойму, как ее вывести в консоль.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> The local variable `c` may not have been initialized

Примерно переводится как

> Локальная переменная `c` может быть не инициализирована.

Компилятор не уверен, что переменная `c` будет инициализирована. Допустим, вы пройдете `if (j < 100)`, но тогда будет шанс, что вы завалите `if (k > j)`, и тогда переменная останется неинициализированной.

Речь идет о том, что вы передаете в ф-ю переменную, которая не была инициализирована, а так нельзя. Вообще неинициализированные примитивы использовать в вычислениях нельзя. С объектами то же самое - от них даже стандартные методы нельзя вызывать.

Решений тут два:
1) Инициализировать переменную изначально.
2) Сделать так, чтобы по ходу программы переменная точно инициализировалась.

Answer (score 1):

Он её видит, но сообщает, что она не инициализирована. Чтобы она инициализировалась, должно выполнится условие. Если, j будет меньше 100 и k <= j, то в переменную "с" не будет записано ни каких значений и будет считана не инициализированная переменная. Компилятор не учитывает значения переменных (j, b, k, d и a) заданных до условий "if" и считает, что переменные в условиях могут иметь разные значения.
Проинициализируйте "с" в самом начале каким-то значением, или измените условия "if", чтобы до считывания в "System.out.println(c);" в эту переменную записывалось значение, например так:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int k, c, j, a, b, d;
    j = 10;
    b = 2000;
    k = 3000;
    d = 4000;
    a = 1;
    с = 0;
    if (j < 100) {
      if (j < 90)
        a = b;
      if (k > j)
        c = k - j;
    } else
      c = d;
    System.out.println(a);
    System.out.println(c);
    System.out.println(k);
}
```

или так:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int k, c, j, a, b, d;
        j = 10;
        b = 2000;
        k = 3000;
        d = 4000;
        a = 1;
        if (j < 100) {
          if (j < 90)
            a = b;
          if (k > j)
            c = k - j;
          else 
          c = d;
        } else
          c = d;
        System.out.println(a);
        System.out.println(c);
        System.out.println(k);
    }
```